# How to make a pendrive write protected?

Tags: usb-flash-drive, read-only

I want to make my pendrive read only.
Its in FAT32 but does to some reason i can't find the usual edit-user permission tab in properties?
Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open Windows CMD (Win Button + r, then type cmd in the box and press enter)
type `diskpart` in the black window
type `list disk`
type `select disk 1\2\3` change the no. according to the list of devices
type `attributes disk set readonly`
voila!